# Sequence of Image Changes on Refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css

**EDIT**: Found the error and fixed it, rather than colors.length it should be theImages.length. Thanks to those who helped.

I got a problem with an array I've been using for a while to change certain images on my blog in a sequence every time you refresh the page. For instance, when you refresh my page, images 1A, 1B, and 1C change to 2A, 2B, and 2C, so on and so forth. After making around 4 different themes for my blog using this array with little to no problems, I'm making a theme which involves 6 different images, which is more than I've usually used. The images only have one alternate set, so when you refresh it goes back and forth between the sets. However, the images have stopped changing on refresh, and I'm stuck with [this](http://trickorterratest.tumblr.com) for my theme when it's supposed to change on refresh. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix it? I've attached the code I've used, if anyone can help I'd be so grateful.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function refreshSequence() {

            //get current cookie value
            var currentIndex = parseInt(getCookie());

            //get image object
            var myImg = document.getElementById('SidebarIcon');

            //declare image directory path and image array
            var thePath = "https://";
            var theImages = ["31.media.tumblr.com/99731e8e83fb073cf39c9384137d9c1f/tumblr_inline_nesxwvNhwO1ql0f75.png", "31.media.tumblr.com/eb31394be711bc9acaae672d81dc979d/tumblr_inline_nesxx2Ay3R1ql0f75.png"]

            var imgPath = thePath + theImages[currentIndex];
            myImg.src = imgPath;

            //get image object
            var myImg = document.getElementById('SidebarPixel');

            //declare image directory path and image array
            var thePath = "https://";
            var theImages = ["31.media.tumblr.com/3c74b0cddf6eea3b464d2d1a7f34e597/tumblr_inline_nesxwgSnSv1ql0f75.png", "31.media.tumblr.com/de88145e72ccb2987d323f4ff8a607d8/tumblr_inline_nesxl0LzRO1ql0f75.png"]

            var imgPath = thePath + theImages[currentIndex];
            myImg.src = imgPath;

             //get image object
            var myImg = document.getElementById('SidebarGIF');

            //declare image directory path and image array
            var thePath = "http://";
            var theImages = ["static.tumblr.com/v2omgmu/bNEnejyu1/terrabg.gif", "static.tumblr.com/v2omgmu/SoXner1tt/terrabg2.gif"]

            var imgPath = thePath + theImages[currentIndex];
            myImg.src = imgPath;

            //get image object
            var myImg = document.getElementById('SidebarBG');

            //declare image directory path and image array
            var thePath = "http://";
            var theImages = ["static.tumblr.com/v2omgmu/LKZnelu4o/background.png", "http://static.tumblr.com/v2omgmu/1DTnesy9e/backgroundthang.png"]

            var imgPath = thePath + theImages[currentIndex];
            myImg.src = imgPath;

            //get image object
            var myImg = document.getElementById('NavIcon');

            //declare image directory path and image array
            var thePath = "https://";
            var theImages = ["31.media.tumblr.com/7b5bc574d9d829df1091687ed4fda3af/tumblr_inline_nesxxnEn5S1ql0f75.png", "31.media.tumblr.com/c083dc983293f5f37d5f827c636ca93f/tumblr_inline_nesxxyNUWz1ql0f75.png"]

            var imgPath = thePath + theImages[currentIndex];
            myImg.src = imgPath;

            //get image object
            var myImg = document.getElementById('SideThing');

            //declare image directory path and image array
            var thePath = "http://";
            var theImages = ["static.tumblr.com/v2omgmu/bgOnesvtn/terrasidething1.png", "static.tumblr.com/v2omgmu/y9nnesvuq/terrasidething2.png"]

            var imgPath = thePath + theImages[currentIndex];
            myImg.src = imgPath;

            //set next cookie index
            currentIndex += 1;
            currentIndex %= colors.length;
            setCookie(currentIndex);
        }

        function setCookie(someint) {
            var now = new Date();
            var addDays = now.getDate() + 7
            now.setDate(addDays); // cookie expires in 7 days
            var theString = 'imgID=' + escape(someint) + ';expires=' + now.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = theString;
        }

        function getCookie() {
            var output = "0";
            if(document.cookie.length > 0) {
                var temp = unescape(document.cookie);
                temp = temp.split(';');
                for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                    if(temp[i].indexOf('imgID') != -1) {
                        temp = temp[i].split('=');
                        output = temp.pop();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return output;
        }

</script>

<body onload="refreshSequence();">

<img id="SidebarIcon">
<img id="SidebarGIF"> etc etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the following variables many times.

```
var myImg = document.getElementById('NavIcon');
var thePath = "https://";
var theImages = []
var imgPath = thePath
```

So the last declaration will be used. So you will not see the page refreshing. Instead you will always get the images which you declared last.

You need to rename the variables/change your logic.

Rename the variables like the following and should work.

```
var myImgNavIcon = document.getElementById('NavIcon');
var thePathNavIcon = "https://";
var theImagesNavIcon = []
var imgPathNavIcon = thePath 

var myImgSidebarIcon = document.getElementById('SidebarIcon');
var thePathSidebarIcon = "https://";
var theImagesSidebarIcon = []
var imgPathSidebarIcon = thePath
```

**Edit: Just re-factored your code for better re-usability.**

```
function setImage(elementId, theImages, currentIndex){
    //get image object
    var myImg = document.getElementById(elementId);

    //declare image directory path and image array
    var thePath = "https://";

    var imgPath = thePath + theImages[currentIndex];
    myImg.src = imgPath;
}

function refreshSequence() {
    //get current cookie value
    var currentIndex = parseInt(getCookie());

    var sideBarImages = ["31.media.tumblr.com/99731e8e83fb073cf39c9384137d9c1f/tumblr_inline_nesxwvNhwO1ql0f75.png", "31.media.tumblr.com/eb31394be711bc9acaae672d81dc979d/tumblr_inline_nesxx2Ay3R1ql0f75.png"]

    var sidebarPixelImages = ["31.media.tumblr.com/3c74b0cddf6eea3b464d2d1a7f34e597/tumblr_inline_nesxwgSnSv1ql0f75.png", "31.media.tumblr.com/de88145e72ccb2987d323f4ff8a607d8/tumblr_inline_nesxl0LzRO1ql0f75.png"]

    var sidebarGIFImages = ["static.tumblr.com/v2omgmu/bNEnejyu1/terrabg.gif", "static.tumblr.com/v2omgmu/SoXner1tt/terrabg2.gif"]

    var sidebarBGImages = ["static.tumblr.com/v2omgmu/LKZnelu4o/background.png", "http://static.tumblr.com/v2omgmu/1DTnesy9e/backgroundthang.png"]

    setImage('SidebarIcon', sideBarImages, currentIndex);
    setImage('SidebarPixel', sidebarPixelImages, currentIndex);
    setImage('SidebarGIF', sidebarGIFImages, currentIndex);
    setImage('SidebarBG', sidebarBGImages, currentIndex);            

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = background;

    //set next cookie index
    currentIndex += 1;
    currentIndex %= colors.length;
    setCookie(currentIndex);
}
```

I have not tested my code. I did this just to give you an idea.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? I'm not very good with HTML/CSS/Java, it's honestly a miracle I was able to get what I have right now going.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome developer tools shows you have this line:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = background;
```

and you have no variable `background` defined, so the code breaks there. Thy removing this line.
And for cookie manipulations it is better to use MDN's [library](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie#Library).

Comment: Ah, that's in there by mistake, I've removed that part of the code in the actual site a while ago and am still met with the same problem.

Comment: @tophergasm it was there 30 minutes ago. Now it is not there and the site works ok now, it seems.